# Save the username & password after login for the first time and not to ask again

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing one ios app, in that I need to enter company-code and accesscode to login. After login for the first time with the access code, We cannot prefer to ask for accesscode again when we open the application. I mean I need to save the preferences.

And my code is here

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {

@try {

    if([[txtsecurecode text] isEqualToString:@""]  || [[OrganizationCode text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Access code" :@"Login Failed!":0];
    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"txtsecurecode=%@ @&password=%@",[txtsecurecode text],[OrganizationCode text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mycompany.com/AccountService/security/ValidateAccess?accesscode=%@&companycode=%@&type=1", txtsecurecode.text, OrganizationCode.text]];


        [[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:OrganizationCode forKey:@"OrganizationCode"];
        [[ NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:txtsecurecode forKey:@"txtsecurecode"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        txtsecurecode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"txtsecurecode"];
        OrganizationCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OrganizationCode"];

       // NSString *num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"txtsecurecode"];

        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if([responseData isEqualToString:@""]){
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter valid Access Code" :@"Login Failed !" :0];
        }
        else
        {

        responseData = [responseData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "" " withString:@""];
        responseData = [responseData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];

        NSString* encodedString = [responseData stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                   NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" ,encodedString);

         UIWebView *webView;
         webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 470)];
         webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         webView.opaque = NO;
         [webView setDelegate:self];

        NSString* urlTwo = [[encodedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%22" withString:@""];

        NSURL *url2;

            if([urlTwo hasPrefix:@"http://"]){
                url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlTwo];
            }else{
                url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@" , urlTwo]];
            }

        NSLog(@"url2:%@", url2);

        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];              

        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

        [[self view] addSubview:webView];

    }
    }

}

@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!" :0];
}
}
```

I had used NSUserDefaults method to save the login credentials but it is not working. Credentials are not saving, again the app is asking for credentials.

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: sorry, before completing the question it is submitted unexpectedly.. @AntonioMG

Comment: In my app need to enter accesscode to login. After login for the first time with the access code, We cannot prefer to ask for accesscode again.. mean I need to save the preferences. @AntonioMG

Comment: then campare  with defaults values when run the app .

Comment: but where is the code you decide to show or skip the login page. If you didn't put any control statements there, of course it will show up every time

Answer (score 1):

try this

when you successfull login then save it in NSUserDefaults

```
    NSUserDefaults *status=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [status setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Login"];
```

Next time only check

```
       NSUserDefaults *objUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];       
       NSString *strSuccess=[objUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Login"];

       if ([strSuccess isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                 // just push the next view.
        }
        else {
             // open login screen
        }
```

**OR** Next option, if you care about security, [the keychain](http://iphoneipad-game.blogspot.in/2012/08/reading-and-storing-values-in-key-chain.html).

**Edit**

.h file

```
  NSUserDefaults *objUserDefaults;
   @property (nonatomic,retain) NSUserDefaults *objUserDefaults;
```

.m file

```
    @synthesize objUserDefaults;
```

Where you first time login Method write this on response\

```
  objUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
  [objUserDefaults setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Login"];

   and when you required for login check then

   NSString *strSuccess=[objUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Login"];

   if ([strSuccess isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
             // just push the next view.
    }
    else {
         // open login screen
    }
```

Comment: its simple take global object of NSUserDefaults and check it, it is 1 or not

Comment: Can you guide me with the code Samir. Its getting late for me as I need to submit to iTunes by today.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you again.. I will send you the code through paste. Can you edit and send me please..

Comment: there is no more code After successful login... I need to load the url through web view after login is successful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29368/discussion-between-kumarsu-and-samir-rathod)

Comment: Please consider posting more answers like this, rather than the ones I've been moderating. This is an example of the kind of answer we like around here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`OrganizationCode` is not a string, and you are getting it as a string with this:

```
OrganizationCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"OrganizationCode"];
```

You need to use `objectForKey:` instead, try with that:

```
OrganizationCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OrganizationCode"];
```

And another thing, OrganizationCode seems like the name of a class, not an instance of an object, are you sure you are using it in the right way?

Comment: I update the code and run the app, The get the logcat as   MOBILE[15599:907]  -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<UITextField: 0x1d0677a0; frame = (14.5 128; 287 42); text = 'text2013'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1d068b80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d0678f0>>' of class 'UITextField'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Answer (score 0):

**To Store: Login Button:**

```
-(IBAction)Login:(id)sender
{
    if (success) {

        NSUserDefaults *status=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [status setObject:@"LOGGING" forKey:@"STATUS"];

        // GO TO NEXT FUNCTION ??
    }

}
```

**To Get:Validation Button:**

```
-(void)load_view
{
    NSUserDefaults *status=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *status_str=[status objectForKey:@"STATUS"];

    if ([status_str isEqualToString:@"LOGGING"]) {
         // GO TO NEXT SUCCESS FUNCTION 
    }
    else
    {
         // GO TO Login View

    }
}
```